# Shell script with ssh command with an if statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, if-statement, ssh

I want to write a shell script to do the following:

1. login some remote machines, say host1 and host2, each at a time
2. go to the /tmp directory and check whether a particular directory named 'dirname' exists or not. If it doesn't exist, make a directory 'dirname'
3. go to the directory /tmp/dirname
4. copy a file with a variable runNo from the local machine to this directory

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work.. any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
#! /bin/bash
dir1=dirname
runNo=0

for i in 1 2
do
  runNo=$(($runNo+1))
  echo "host$i runNo$runNo"

  ssh host$i "cd /tmp;
    if [ -d $dir1 ]; then
      cd $dir1;
    else
      mkdir $dir1;
      cd $dir1;
    fi;
    cp ~/local/file$runNo file"

  echo "done"
done
```

Comment: Instead of testing if `$dir1` exists, just use `mkdir -p "$dir1"`. If it already exists, nothing happens.

Comment: That said, never `cd` to a directory without checking if the cd succeeded. `if mkdir -p "/tmp/$dir1" && cd "/tmp/$dir1"; then … else [handle error]; fi`

Comment: Also, try starting smaller to see if it ssh works... `ssh host$i "cd /tmp; touch imhere"` see if the the file `imhere` exists in the remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
ssh host$i "mkdir -p /tmp/$dir1"
scp ~/local/file$runNo host$i:/tmp/$dir1/file
```

`mkdir -p` suppresses errors if the directory already exists.

Comment: I think the `cp ~/local/...` bit is also not what he wants (unless he has some fancy NFS setup he didn't explain).  He probably needs a separate `scp` line inside the loop.

Comment: @dg99, thanks, I wasn't paying close enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

Like this perhaps?

```
runNo=1
for h in host1 host2; do
    cat ~/local/file$runNo |
    ssh "$h" 'mkdir -p /tmp/dirname; cat >/tmp/dirname/file'
    runNo=$(($runNo+1))
done
```

If I interpret your description correctly, the `cd` is superfluous.

If Bourne shell compatibility is necessary, you can replace the increment with

```
    runNo=$(expr $runNo + 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ssh -t -t host$i <<eod1
echo "your command goes here"
add eod1 to terminate your ssh
eod1
```

Note two -t -t is required to overwrite the sudo terminal error

this editing rules is driving me crazy